# Dependency Error while installing LibreOffice on RHEL

Tags: dependencies, installation, package, yum, libreoffice

I'm quite new to Red Hat so sorry for this possibly dump question.

I want to install LibreOffice. Therefore I downloaded the tar.gz from libreoffice.org. After extracting the files I run as root: `yum install *.rpm`. This results in the following output:

```
[root@oc0715621235 RPMS]# yum install *.rpm
Loaded plugins: downloadonly-background, fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Examining libobasis4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core02-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core02-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core02-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core03-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core03-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core03-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core04-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core04-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core04-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core05-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core05-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core05-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core06-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core06-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core06-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core07-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core07-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core07-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-res-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-res-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-res-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-gnome-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-gnome-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-gnome-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-graphicfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-graphicfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-graphicfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-images-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-images-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-images-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-javafilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-javafilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-javafilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-kde-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-kde-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-kde-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-librelogo-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-librelogo-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-librelogo-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-ogltrans-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-ogltrans-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-ogltrans-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-onlineupdate-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-onlineupdate-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-onlineupdate-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-ooofonts-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-ooofonts-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-ooofonts-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-pyuno-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-pyuno-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-pyuno-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-xsltfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-xsltfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-xsltfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libreoffice4.0-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-dict-en-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-dict-en-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-dict-es-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-dict-es-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-dict-fr-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-dict-fr-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libobasis4.0-base.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-calc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-core01.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libreoffice4.0-ure for package: libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
---> Package libobasis4.0-core02.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-core03.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-core04.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-core05.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-core06.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-core07.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-draw.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-base.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-calc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-math.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-res.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-writer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-gnome-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-graphicfilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-images.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-impress.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-javafilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-kde-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-librelogo.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-math.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-ogltrans.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-onlineupdate.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-ooofonts.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-pyuno.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-writer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
---> Package libobasis4.0-xsltfilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64 (/libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64)
           Requires: libreoffice4.0-ure
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@oc0715621235 RPMS]#
```

Neither of the suggestions above did work (`--skip-broken` and `rpm -Va ...`)

From my point of view it seems like `libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64` is expecting the package `libreoffice4.0-ure` but there is only a package called `libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm`.

Therefore I also tried an older version of LibreOffice. But I ran into the same error with version 3.6.6

Any suggestions how I can enjoy LibreOffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install `libreoffice4.0-ure` first and then the rest.

To do so:

`rpm -iv libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm`

and then:

`yum localinstall --verbose *.rpm`

Comment: This finally (almost) worked.
After installing with yum for some reasons I had to manually install each of the `libreoffice4.0-*.rpm` because yum hadn't include them. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> From my point of view it seems like libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64 is expecting the package libreoffice4.0-ure but there is only a package called libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm.

The error is telling you the name of the package, not the full nevra (so both of the above things refer to the same package name=libreoffice4.0-ure, version=4.0.2.2, ...).

The main question to solving this problem is why it says "examining *-ure" but then doesn't try to install it. Having a higher logging level might help, also you can try using the tmprepo plugin (as yum doesn't work perfectly with large numbers of local packages).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You find more detailed infos on my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more output as requested from James:

`yum --verbose install *.rpm`

```
[markus@thinkpad RPMS]$ sudo yum -v install *.rpm
Not loading "blacklist" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "downloadonly-background" plugin
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "refresh-packagekit" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Loading "tmprepo" plugin
Loading "versionlock" plugin
Not loading "whiteout" plugin, as it is disabled
Config time: 0.037
Added repo: RHEL-64-x86_64-updates
Added repo: RHEL-64-x86_64
Added repo: RHEL-6-x86_64-rational-linux
Added repo: RHEL-6-x86_64-openafs
Yum Version: 3.2.29
Setting up Package Sacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * nux-libreoffice.org-rpms: li.nux.ro
Building updates object
rpmdb time: 0.000
up:Obs Init time: 0.109
up:simple updates time: 0.026
up:obs time: 0.003
up:condense time: 0.000
updates time: 1.066
Reading version lock configuration
pkgsack time: 1.143
Setting up Install Process
Examining libobasis4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core02-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core02-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core02-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core03-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core03-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core03-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core04-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core04-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core04-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core05-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core05-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core05-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core06-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core06-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core06-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-core07-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-core07-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-core07-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-res-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-res-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-res-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-en-US-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-en-US-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-en-US-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-gnome-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-gnome-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-gnome-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-graphicfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-graphicfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-graphicfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-images-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-images-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-images-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-javafilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-javafilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-javafilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-kde-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-kde-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-kde-integration-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-librelogo-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-librelogo-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-librelogo-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-ogltrans-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-ogltrans-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-ogltrans-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-onlineupdate-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-onlineupdate-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-onlineupdate-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-ooofonts-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-ooofonts-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-ooofonts-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-pyuno-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-pyuno-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-pyuno-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libobasis4.0-xsltfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libobasis4.0-xsltfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Marking libobasis4.0-xsltfilter-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining libreoffice4.0-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-base-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-calc-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-dict-en-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-dict-en-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-dict-en-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-dict-es-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-dict-es-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-dict-es-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-dict-fr-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-dict-fr-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-dict-fr-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-draw-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-en-US-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-impress-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-math-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Examining libreoffice4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Excluding libreoffice4.0-writer-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libobasis4.0-base.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-base.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-base.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-calc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-calc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-calc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-core01.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-core01.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libreoffice4.0-ure', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-core01.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64 requires: libreoffice4.0-ure
--> Processing Dependency: libreoffice4.0-ure for package: libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Searching pkgSack for dep: libreoffice4.0-ure
---> Package libobasis4.0-core02.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-core02.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-core02.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-core03.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-core03.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-core03.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-core04.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-core04.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-core04.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libfreetype.so.6()(64bit)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-core04.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-core05.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-core05.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-core05.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-core06.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-core06.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-core06.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-core07.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-core07.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-core07.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-draw.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-draw.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-draw.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-en-US.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-en-US.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-base.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-en-US-base.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-en-US', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-en-US-base.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-calc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-en-US-calc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-en-US', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-en-US-calc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-math.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-en-US-math.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-en-US', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-en-US-math.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-res.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-en-US-res.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-en-US', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-en-US-res.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-en-US-writer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-en-US-writer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-en-US', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-en-US-writer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core02', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core03', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core04', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core05', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core06', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core07', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core02', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core03', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core04', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core05', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core06', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core07', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-javascript-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core02', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core03', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core04', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core05', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core06', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core07', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core02', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core03', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core04', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core05', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core06', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core07', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-nlpsolver.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core02', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core03', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core04', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core05', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core06', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core07', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-presentation-minimizer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core02', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core03', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core04', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core05', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core06', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core07', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-python-script-provider.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core02', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core03', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core04', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core05', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core06', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core07', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-extension-report-builder.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-gnome-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-gnome-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-gnome-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libgnomevfs-2.so.0()(64bit)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-gnome-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit)', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-gnome-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-graphicfilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-graphicfilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-graphicfilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-images.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-images.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-images.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-impress.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-impress.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-impress.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-javafilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-javafilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-javafilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-kde-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-kde-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-kde-integration.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-librelogo.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-librelogo.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-librelogo.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-writer', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-librelogo.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-math.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-math.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-math.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-ogltrans.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-ogltrans.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-impress', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-ogltrans.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-onlineupdate.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-onlineupdate.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-onlineupdate.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-ooofonts.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-ooofonts.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-ooofonts.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-ooolinguistic.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-base', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-postgresql-sdbc.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-pyuno.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-pyuno.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-pyuno.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-writer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-writer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-writer.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
---> Package libobasis4.0-xsltfilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 will be installed
Checking deps for libobasis4.0-xsltfilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
looking for ('libobasis4.0-core01', None, (None, None, None)) as a requirement of libobasis4.0-xsltfilter.x86_64 0:4.0.2.2-2 - u
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Dependency Process ending
Depsolve time: 2.921
Error: Package: libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64 (/libobasis4.0-core01-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64)
           Requires: libreoffice4.0-ure
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What should be mentioned is, that if I try to only install `yum install libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm` i get the error "Nothing to do":

```
[markus@thinkpad RPMS]$ sudo yum install libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm 
Loaded plugins: downloadonly-background, fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security, tmprepo, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Examining libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64.rpm: libreoffice4.0-ure-4.0.2.2-2.x86_64
Error: Nothing to do
```

I didn't test tmprepo as I wasn't able to find a .repo file of libreoffice for RHEL.